# Get Id from first table in transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I got this two tables for example [image]

and I need to made transaction that input data in this tables. How can I get Id that is input in firstTable, and set it as Foreign key FirstTableId in second table?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO FirsTable (Name) VALUES ('example1')

INSERT INTO SecondTable (Name, FirstTableId) VALUES ('example2', ?)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `id` is an `identity`, Use `@@IDENTITY` as next:-

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO FirsTable (Name) VALUES ('example1')

INSERT INTO SecondTable (Name, FirstTableId) VALUES ('example2', @@IDENTITY)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

For More [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx).

**UPDATE:-**

For Non identity columns, Use table variable to get id via using `Output`, as next:-

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @table table (id int)

INSERT INTO FirsTable (Name) 
OUTPUT inserted.id into @table
VALUES ('example1')
SELECT @id = id from @table

INSERT INTO SecondTable (Name, FirstTableId) VALUES ('example2',  @id)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

For More [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! What if I got another (third) INSERT in this transaction and I need get Id of firstTable?

Comment: There is no any issue, via this code `INSERT INTO FirsTable (Name) 
OUTPUT inserted.id into @table
VALUES ('example1')
SELECT @id = id from @table` you reserved the id that inserted in first table into `@id` variable, so use it whatever you want.